# AWS Lambda Python dictionaries issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I'm trying to fetch data from an API with AWS Lambda and Python, my code runs locally but an error occurs when I test it on AWS Lambda, it seems to not recognize my dictionary and tells me I cannot perform dict operations on a list.
By the way, AWS Lambda is new to me, I may not understand some basic concepts, feel free to educate me.

Here's a snippet of the code :

```py
    reponse = get_data(
        agence,
        convert_TS(start),
        convert_TS(end),
        freq
    )
    df_agence = pd.DataFrame()
    print(reponse)
    for col in reponse.keys():
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(reponse[col])
        df.columns = ["TS", col]
        df["agence"] = unidecode.unidecode(agence).lower() 
        df["TS"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TS"], origin="unix", unit='ms')
        df.set_index(["TS", "agence"], inplace=True)
        df_agence = pd.concat([df_agence, df], axis=1)
```

where get_data() is :

```py
response = requests.get(
                request_url,
                headers=request_headers,
                params=query_params
            )
if response.status_code != 200:
   raise Exception("Request returned status_code : %s" % response.status_code)

   period_stats = response.json()
   period_records = period_stats["records"]
   return period_records
```

the json response from get_data :

```json
    {'success': True, 'records': {'a1': [[1624891500000, 219], [1624892400000, 220.66666666666666], [1624893300000, 226.66666666666666], [1624894200000, 236.33333333333334], [1624895100000, 223], [1624896000000, 231.66666666666666], [1624896900000, 229.33333333333334], [1624897800000, 224.66666666666666], [1624898700000, 219.66666666666666], [1624899600000, 214]], 'Pdc': [[1624891500000, 296.178670757], [1624892400000, 293.19934584699996], [1624893300000, 298.13666716866663], [1624894200000, 293.5046666133333], [1624895100000, 250.81833203000005], [1624896000000, 327.91799436799994], [1624896900000, 303.7520111763333], [1624897800000, 286.403998991], [1624898700000, 188.474998951], [1624899600000, 98.4360015144]]}, 'totals': {'a1': 2245, 'Pdc': 2636.822687416733}}
```

I get the response, and return only the "records" and the type of the variable is a dict.
The error is only on AWS Lambda but works fine on local:

```
START RequestId: 2c3f4780-6f6c-41a2-b124-254cada439fb Version: $LATEST
'list' object has no attribute 'keys': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 18, in lambda_handler
    vrm_data = get_vrm(start=TS, end=current_date)
  File "/var/task/get_vrm_data_historical.py", line 31, in get_vrm
    for col in reponse.keys():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

It seems to not recognize the variable "reponse" as a dict but I checked the type and it returned : <class 'dict'>.
If you have any clue what is happening, let me know !

Comment: ```period_stats = response.json()``` is this supposed to be inside your if statement or outside it?

Comment: Just do `for col in reponse:` it iterate over the keys

Comment: @jsfehler it is outside of the if statement

Comment: @azro works locally but it gave me another error on AWS Lambda when I droplevel later on the code to remove an index column of the dataframe, it says that the dataframe has only 1 index level when it should have 2

Comment: Can you print `response.json()`?

Comment: `{'success': True, 'records': {'a1': [[1624923000000, 40.333333333333336], [1624923900000, 41]], 'Pdc': [[1624923000000, 0], [1624923900000, 0]]}, 'totals': {'a1': 81.33333333333334, 'Pdc': 0}}`is the`response.json()`